# EntityValidationErrors inserting null datetime value

Tags: c#, .net, entity

I'm trying to save a null value to a datetime column on a MS SQL database.
Whenever an exception is thrown and the dob property is set to null then db.savechanges throws the following error:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

It might seem redundant but would `holterContents.dob = null as DateTime?;` make a difference?

```
try
{
    holterContents.dob = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(infopatlines[38]), Convert.ToInt32(infopatlines[39]),
    Convert.ToInt32(infopatlines[40]));
}

catch (Exception a)
{
    holterContents.dob = null;
    Log.Error(a.Message);
}
db.C_HOLTERCONTENTS.Add(holterContents);
db.savechanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it going to Catch block?

If its not going to catch block check our date "01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM". If its coming like this then you need to set it as 'null'

Put your Save block in Try block with

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                  .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                  .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);
            // Join the list to a single string.
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);
            // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);
            // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }
```

Check what type of error is coming...

Comment: It's going to catch block, and I've set up logging to a log table.. I can see that it's either updated to Null at catch or I can change it to something more legitimate using new datetime(1995,1,1)

I think I may have found the culprit tho, another property of holtercontents thats a string with 100 trailing white spaces thats trying to get inserted into a nvarchar(50) column.

I'll test and get back to you, thanks for the help